# Can't inject ngx-toastr service in HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr

I'm developing a web app with Angular v. 12.2.4.

I am trying to display notification toasts upon HTTP errors, using the ngx-toastr library (v. 14.2.1). Using the Angular HTTP interceptor functionality, I'm trying to inject the ToasterService into my custom interceptor class, only to get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this._appRef.attachView is not a function
    at Ke.attachComponentPortal (ngx-toastr.mjs:280)
    at Ke.attach (ngx-toastr.mjs:79)
    at tt.attach (ngx-toastr.mjs:310)
    at dt._buildNotification (ngx-toastr.mjs:597)
    at dt._preBuildNotification (ngx-toastr.mjs:560)
    at dt.error (ngx-toastr.mjs:472)
    at S.selector (toastr.interceptor.ts:23)
    at S.error (catchError.js:29)
    at j.observe (Notification.js:22)
    at M._next (dematerialize.js:17)
```

**ToastrInterceptor.ts:**

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ERROR_MESSAGES } from 'src/app/utils/config/modal-settings';

@Injectable()
export class ToastrInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private toastrService: ToastrService) { }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                console.error(error);

                let msg;

                if (error?.error?.message !== undefined)
                    msg = error.error.message;
                else
                    msg = ERROR_MESSAGES[error.status] || ERROR_MESSAGES[0];

                this.toastrService.error(msg)
                console.log("ERROR MESSAGE", msg);
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Any help/leads on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using Injector: https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/179.